# SFTP with 2fa activated on Ubuntu Server 20.04 not working

Tags: ssh, sftp, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-20.04

I just enabled 2fa for ssh on my Ubuntu 20.04 server. I followed this tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#3-configuring-authentication

With this being clarified I am using libpam-google-authenticator for this task.

I can conncect to my server via ssh and it works. But now I noticed I can not use sftp anymore, my client just closes (putty included psftp.exe for this, which I am using)

I am just experimenting with my server since it does not have anything important on it.(and I do not have much experience with servers)

Can anyone help me with this? Any help is appreciated.